# Azure App Service - REST API with slash in url param

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, httprequest

My Azure App Service is a REST API.

Buy it is unable to handle correctly http requests with parameters that contains a slash `/`.

For example. my api is `/api/do_something_with/{PARAM}`

When `{PARAM}` contains a slash `/` (for example `AAA%2FBBB`) it arrives to the app already decoded and `%2F` becomes a `/` in (`AAA/BBB`)

As you can understand, resulting url becomes `/api/do_something_with/AAA/445` (not found).

Do you know how to avoid this behaviour?

Please note, there are many workaround to avoid this problem.
I wrote this question because I want try to understand how to make the things work properly.

For what is my understanding, a Azure App Service as a container which exposes web applications that can be written in many languages. Trying to understand this problem I've deployed two web app (Java and Python) and in both cases the app recevies the slash already decoded. For my understanding is the app service that should be configured properly, I don't understand how.

Comment: Put a **?** in front of the {PARAM} to make it a query parameter. Example **/api/do_something_with/?AAA/445

Comment: @JohnHanley thanks, well, I already did it. I wrote this question to understand how to do it properly

Comment: I do not see that in your question. I have commented on how to do it correctly. Otherwise, another option is to modify your routes handler.

Comment: @JohnHanley right, I've just update the question ;)

Comment: This is not a situation of a workaround. You are specifying a parameter as part of the path. You can either convert that to a query parameter or modify your routes handler. Your question does not mention the framework or the language or the runtime environment. Details matter to get good answers.

Comment: @JohnHanley Again, I've updated my question to give a more complete view. I agree that details matter, but in this case even changing language  or runtime environement the problem remains. I think is the app service that should be configured properly.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with app service. It is decoding the URL correctly. If you do not want the URL decoded change **%2F** to **%%2F**.  However, that is a bandaid and I would never do that. Your route handler might not like that either.

Comment: Azure function app have a similar problem. Please read this https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1042

Comment: Please do not argue advice. If you do not accept the advice, then ignore it. If you read the link you provided you will see the issues with what you want to do. You are trying to embed a parameter into the URL. The framework determines if that will work. If you need the param unprocessed then encode that part. I suggested one method **%%2F**, your link provides another **%252F** and another which is to base64 encode the param. I also suggested modifying your routes handler which your link also discusses.

Answer (score 1):

Have been struggeling with this issue for 2 days. I found a solution which worked for me.
Insted of `%2F` try `%252F` this is also used for escaping  / .

Cheers!!